# What JavaScript code do I run when the user closes the tab?

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

**Summarize the problem**

I'm trying to create a macOS tabbed web browser using WKWebView and Swift. Everything works fine except the webpage doesn't know I closed the tab. I want to tell the webpage that I closed the tab

**Describe what you've tried**

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to do

**Show some code**

I've tried doing this

`webView.removeFromSuperView()`

But the webpage didn't know that I closed the tab

---

I don't know much javascript so please include code instead of explaining

Comment: hmm if you close the page, it's dead, doesn't exist anymore. So what's the point to notify it?

Comment: You could technically just add a function to the close tab button that flags when the tab is closed, otherwise I concur with @KirilS.

Comment: @KirilS., I mean, there's `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` events that some scripts rely on - so, this is a real use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript scripts use `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` events to tap into browser closing.

Since you know the browser is about to close, you can dispatch this event yourself. For example, with `beforeunload` event:

```
let script = """
   const event = new Event("beforeunload", { cancellable: true });
   const cancelled = !window.dispatch(event);
   // return back whether the user cancelled
   cancelled;
"""
```

When you need to close the browser, invoke the script:

```
let webView = WKWebView()
// ... other config
webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: { result, error in
   guard let cancelled = result else { return }
  
   if cancelled == 1 {
     // ... do whatever
   }
})
```